# Snowflake sequence not generating continuous numbers

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to migrate data from sql server to snowflake.I created a table with an autoincrement column in snowflake so that when i push the data from sql i get an identity column.But after the first load when i tried to load the data again i could see that the values in the identity column is starting from some random place and not from where i expected.
I tried with sequence also but still same issue.When i inserted 40 records into to the table i could see the identity column having values from 1 to 40.But when i tried to insert another value the sequence started from 118.I am not able to understand this issue.Could anyone help me??

I tried identity column,then autoincrement and sequence generator.

Comment: Hi from the Snowflake Documentation it says that " There is no guarantee that values from a sequence are contiguous (gap-free) or that the sequence values are assigned in a particular order. ...."   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-sequences  Please let us know how it impacts you, If you have the numbers with a gap in a sequence.

Comment: Why do you care wher it starts from? Usually Identities are used to generate unique numbers and making any assumption about where they start from, or whether they have gaps will get you into trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Snowflake does not guarantee generating sequence numbers with no gaps. Sequences will wrap around after reaching the maximum positive integer value for the data type"

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-sequences.html#sequence-semantics

Snowflake utilizes an internal sequence to generate the values for the identity column, and it does not guarantee to generate gap-free sequence numbers. This is because of Snowflake caches "sequence values" when they are started to use in a batch insert. Instead of getting one value at a time, it asks for a range of values (e.g. 256, 512, 1024 and so on...) to allow for efficient parallelism. Therefore when inserting more rows, the gap might occur.

You can consider using the ROW_NUMBER window function.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html#row-number

Comment: Just keep in mind `ROW_NUMBER` will definitely not guarantee a unique identifier. i.e. for two different runs you'll always get a 1